# How would I go about drawing a rectangular selection on-screen when the mouse is dragged and then getting a screenshot of the selected area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking for a way to draw a rectangular selection-visualiser, basically similar to Gyazo.

If any of you are familiar with iOS jailbreaking and have used Snapper 2 before, I'm trying to do that but for Windows. For those of you who aren't, it allows you to select an area you want for a screenshot and then keeps it on top of everything else, allowing you to drag it around, save it etc. It's really useful for phone numbers, WiFi passwords among other things.

The only issue is that I don't know how I'd go about drawing a selection area and grabbing an image of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows since 7 has the Snipping tool. It might be close enough to the droid you are looking for: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots

If you mean .NET with C#, there is [Graphics.CopyFromScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1kt6f9.aspx). Note that it does not work from Windows services - a interactive session is required and Services are [barred from those](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by default since Vista.

One issues is having this thing be drawn "on top". Generally the topmost game is one you and the user [can only loose](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253). Everything that is able to win it is either part of Windows itself. Or uses a "intercept GPU output, draw something on top" approach, wich is not trivial.